# Como insertar una imagen en una página Web con PHP

Tags: php, html5

-Buenas tardes,
Soy completamente nuevo en desarrollo Web...
Quería crear una tabla con una imagen de la carpeta al lado de folder1, folder2, folder3.

Este es mi código...pero no me pinta la imagen, solo resource3#...
Muchas gracias. Saludos.

```
<?php
    $arrCarpetas = array("Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3");
    $folderImg= imagecreatefrompng("folder.png");
   /*
     if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
        echo "El soporte para PNG está habilitado";
     }
   **/

  $strHtml="<table border='1'>";

  /*reset--> moves the internal pointer to the first element of the array.**/ 
  $strFolders=reset($arrCarpetas);

  $strHtml.="<th>FOLDERS</th>";

  $strHtml.="<tbody>";


  foreach ($arrCarpetas as $row)
  {
    $strHtml.= "<tr>";
    $strHtml.="<td>".$folderImg."</td>";
    $strHtml.= "<td>".$row."</td>";
   }

   $strHtml.="</table>";
   echo $strHtml;
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($folderImg);`?

Comment: Debes aprender bien html antes de meterle de lleno al desarrollo web. Esa rutina crea una tabla mal formada. Faltan todos los cierres `</tr>` y el cierre `</tbody>` además de los respectivos `<tr></tr>` que envuelve al `<th>...</th>` (que le falta otra columna o un `rowspan`). Si no vas a procesar las imágenes, se puede mostrar simplemente con `<img src="folder.png">` según [la documentación](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/img)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar tu `foreach` de este modo.
Y darle el tamaño que quieras, además de centrar el icono.
Eso si, tienes que solo insertar la imagen.

```
$folderImg = "folder.png";
```

.

```
foreach ($arrCarpetas as $row) {
    $strHtml .= "<tr>";
    $strHtml .= "<td align='center'> <img src='".$folderImg."' width='30px'> </td>";
    $strHtml .= "<td>" . $row . "</td>";
}
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]